# Is it possible to run Comos DB inside docker-compose with Table API option

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

**Azure Cosmos DB** has an option called **Table API**, I'm using it and I really enjoy, but the problem it is that I need to run my environment on **docker-compose** and I don't know if it's possible. When we are developing, we can use the **Azure Comos DB Emulator** e run a command **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /EnableTableEndpoint** that enable us to developing locally using the Table API but we don't have this options when running on docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docker container, this can be done via the environment variable approach.

Set `AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_TABLES_ENDPOINT=true` in your docker-compose file for the emulator, and it should start with Tables API working.

Comment: Hello @Chris the problem it's that **Azure Cosmos Emulator Docker Container**  does not work on Linux containers, so whether I'm using a simple Cosmos Db instance I can use a Mongo image, but this is not possible when using **Table APIs**

Comment: That's correct. Currently Cosmos DB relies on some pretty deep Windows APIs that aren't easy to abstract away (we've tried haha) in the emulator. We might try and approach like [Azurite](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite) has done for Storage, in the future, but in the mean time, you're probably stuck using a cloud hosted instance. The Cosmos DB Free Tier was created with that in mind.

Comment: Thanks again @Chris, I've read about this solution, of using the **Cosmos DB Free Tier** and this can solve my problem, but on Azure Account I have other Cosmos Db Accounts and when I try to create a new one for development purpose it isn't free

Comment: Yeah, understand it is not perfect. We're working on more stuff that will hopefully help.